# Showing dates of specific weekday in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` and I want to show only the dates of specific weekday in of the picker.

For example, if I select `Mon 26 March` then I should only see

- 2 April,
- 9 April,
- 16 April,
- 23 April

and so on in the `UIDatePicker`. How can this be achieved using `UIDatePicker`

Answer (score 0):

I Think there is no build-in functionality that can be used to accomplish this , you can create a pickerView and get week dates by adding this to the current

```
extension Date
{
   var nextDateWeak : Date {
       return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6 , to: self )!
   }
}
```